# com.google.android not found

Tags: android, android-things

I'm new to Android, but old to programming. I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1.  I'm trying to do some UART things as described at https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart .

When I try to code this line:

```
PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
```

The word "PeripheralManager" is red, meaning it's not found.  I think what I need is this line near the top of my code:

```
import com.google.android.things.pio.PeripheralManager;
```

it highlights "android" in red.  When I mouse over, I get a popup message "cannot resolved symbol 'android'".

I think this is because I need to add something to my project or environment, and THIS is what I can't figure out.  I've seen other posts that get close, but they don't seem to apply correctly.

Please remember, I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1.  When I click on Tools / SDK Manager, and look at the SDK Tools tab, I see some "Google..." items.  I installed "Google Play services", but that didn't fix the problem.  "Google Repository" is already checked.  Just now I checked ALL of the "Google Play..." items, but it still didn't help.

Exactly HOW do I make this work?  Detailed instructions are greatly appreciated...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/things/training/first-device/create-studio-project#library

Comment: You are probably missing something from the gradle file. Follow either pskink's link or [Android Things Code Lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidthings-peripherals/#0)

Comment: Did you add the Android things library to your gradle?